# How to load data using XHR in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am experimenting with D3 on my localhost. I would like to load data to be visualized from an external source on the Internet.

I am looking for instruction/examples of how to how to load data using XHR in D3 (there is documentation here, but it does not suffice for me, I am looking for code snippets https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)

I have tried the following and it does not work for me:

```
d3.xhr("http://example.org/json-test.json", function(data){

    alert(data); //no data is returned

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of D3, the first argument of the callback is the error, if any, and the second the data. No data in the first argument (which you're checking) suggests that the request was successful. See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_xhr) for more details.

Comment: I have the same problem. `d3.xhr("http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/aaa/bbb/?format=json", function(error, nodes){` shows me undefined(nodes).The url works because if I open this on browser it shows me the json

Comment: Yes. An alert shows me:`[object XMLHttpRequest]`. I also do error.toSource and shows me `({})`

Comment: You may want to ask a separate question about this, but this is almost certainly something specific to your setup.

Comment: I also believe that, but I don't handle the setup, so now  burn some neurons :D

Answer (score 2):

### update to the update:

The d3-request module has been superseded by the [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) module.  It handles JSON, CSV, TSV and plain text.

### update:

Just in case someone arrives here looking for `xhr` in d3: this functionality is now supported in the [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) module.

Answer (score 0):

Your function callback should look like this

```
                                                       v---- missing param
d3.xhr("http://example.org/json-test.json", function(error, data){
    // code...
});
```

That is the typical callback structure in javascript/node.js, `error` first then `data`.