# Dynamic JSON not loading - D3.js Line chart

Tags: json, d3.js

I am a beginner in D3.js. I am trying to create a simple Line chart using Dynamic JSON in D3js. For some reason i am not able to parse the JSON properly and the axes is not updated properly. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

 body {
 font: 10px sans-serif;
 }

 .axis path,
 .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

 .axis text
  {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 13px;
  }

  .tick
  {
   stroke-dasharray: 1,2;
   }

  .bar
  {
  fill: FireBrick;
  }

 </style>

  <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"               src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   d3.xhr("http://104.131.191.213/books/", "application/json", function (error, data) {
   if (error) return console.warn(error);
      d = JSON.parse(data.response);
      d = d3.entries(d);
      d.forEach(function(d1){
      d1.value.forEach(function(d) {
      d.year = +d.year;
      d.buys = +d.buys;


      var vis=d3.select ("#visualisation"),
         width=1000,
         height=500,
         MARGINS={top:20,right:20,bottom:20,left:50},
         xRange = d3.time.scale()
           .range([MARGINS.left, width - MARGINS.right])
           .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.year; }),
            d3.max(data,function(d) { return d.year; })]), 
         yRange = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom])
            .domain([d3.min(data,function(d){
            return d.buys; }),
         d3.max(data, function(d) { 
         return d.buys; })]),

        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(xRange)
       .tickSize(5)
       .tickSubdivide(true),

        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(yRange)
       .tickSize(5)
       .orient("left")
       .tickSubdivide(true);

        vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

        vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);


        var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return xRange(d.year); })   
        .y(function(d) { return yRange(d.buys); })
        .interpolate('linear');

        vis.append("svg:path")

       .attr("d", lineFunc(data))
       .attr("stroke","blue")
       .attr("stroke-width",2)
       .attr("fill","none");
        });
        });
        })
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
           <svg id="Visualisation" width="1000" height="500"> </svg>
        </body>
        </html>
```

JSON below:

```
{
  "data": [
   {
     "buys": 5841, 
     "year": "1986"
   }, 
   {
      "buys": 54, 
      "year": "1954"
   }, 
   {
      "buys": 176, 
      "year": "1967"
   }, 
   {
      "buys": 9389, 
      "year": "1991"
   }, 
   {
      "buys": 63, 
      "year": "1953"
   }, 
   {
      "buys": 1, 
      "year": "1910"
   }, 
   {
      "buys": 3, 
      "year": "2006"
   }
   ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

May in url you will metion file name

```
http://104.131.191.213/books/filename instead of http://104.131.191.213/books/
```

For your solution see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970578/how-do-i-post-parameter-on-d3-json)
and se [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300942/how-to-load-data-using-xhr-in-d3)